# Deriving circe Codec for a sealed case class family where base trait has a (sealed) type member

Tags: json, scala, shapeless, circe

I can easily generically derive a codec for a sealed case class family like this:

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

sealed trait Base
case class X(x: Int) extends Base
case class Y(y: Int) extends Base

object Test extends App {
  val encoded = Encoder[Base].apply(Y(1))
  val decoded = Decoder[Base].apply(encoded.hcursor)
  println(decoded) // Right(Y(1))
}
```

However, if I add a type member to the base class I can't do it anymore, even if it's bounded by a sealed trait:

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.auto._

sealed trait Inner
case class I1(i: Int) extends Inner
case class I2(s: String) extends Inner

sealed trait Base { type T <: Inner }
case class X[S <: Inner](x: S) extends Base { final type T = S }
case class Y[S <: Inner](y: S) extends Base { final type T = S }

object Test extends App {
  val encodedInner = Encoder[Inner].apply(I1(1))
  val decodedInner = Decoder[Inner].apply(encodedInner.hcursor) // Ok
  println(decodedInner) // Right(I1(1))

  // Doesn't work: could not find implicit for Encoder[Base] etc
  // val encoded = Encoder[Base].apply(Y(I1(1)))
  // val decoded = Decoder[Base].apply(encoded.hcursor)
  // println(decoded)
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve what I want? If not, what can I change to get something similar?

Comment: What if you tried with the aux pattern? e.g. `type Aux[A <: Input] = Base { type T = A }` then extend from `Aux`? Also, do you really need it to be a type member?

Comment: In fact, seems your case classes could just take a `Inner` as their argument instead of an `S <: Inner`.

Comment: I added an answer, but have since revised it to add more detail and explanation, as well as a better implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason this doesn't work is because you are trying to essentially do

```
Encoder[Base { type T }]
```

without saying what type `T` is. This is analogous to expecting this function to compile -

```
def foo[A] = implicitly[Encoder[List[A]]]
```

You need to explicitly refine your type.

One way to approach this is with the `Aux` pattern. You can't use the typical `type Aux[S] = Base { type T = S }` since that won't give you the coproduct when trying to derive the instance (the `X` and `Y` classes can't extend from a type alias). Instead, we could hack around it by creating another sealed trait as `Aux` and have our case classes extend from that.

So long as all of your case classes extend from `Base.Aux` instead of directly from `Base`, you can use the following which abuses `.asInstanceOf` to appease the type system.

```
sealed trait Inner
case class I1(i: Int) extends Inner
case class I2(s: String) extends Inner

sealed trait Base { type T <: Inner }
object Base {
  sealed trait Aux[S <: Inner] extends Base { type T = S }
  implicit val encoder: Encoder[Base] = {
    semiauto.deriveEncoder[Base.Aux[Inner]].asInstanceOf[Encoder[Base]]
  }
  implicit val decoder: Decoder[Base] = {
    semiauto.deriveDecoder[Base.Aux[Inner]].asInstanceOf[Decoder[Base]]
  }
}

val encoded = Encoder[Base].apply(Y(I1(1)))
val decoded = Decoder[Base].apply(encoded.hcursor)
```

Note that a lot of this depends on how you are actually using your types. I would imagine that you wouldn't rely on calling `Encoder[Base]` directly and would instead use `import io.circe.syntax._` and call the `.asJson` extension method. In that case, you may be able to rely on an `Encoder[Base.Aux[S]]` instance which would be inferred depending on the value being encoded/decoded. Something like the following may suffice for your use case without resorting to `.asInstanceOf` hacks.

```
implicit def encoder[S <: Inner : Encoder]: Encoder[Base.Aux[S]] = {
  semiauto.deriveEncoder
}
```

Again, it all depends on how you are using the instances. I'm skeptical that you actually need a type member in `Base`, things would be simpler if you moved it to a generic param so the deriver could figure out the coproduct for you.

Comment: The type member is there for a reason that is out of scope, it can certainly be removed but it would overload syntax with lots of cascading type parameters everywhere. It surely can be done differently, but that's not the point I guess.

Comment: Also, how would you extend from Base.Aux where Aux is a type member of the companion? Aux is just a type alias, you cannot extend it afaik, I don't see the difference anyway